# Create new key-value pairs using useContext and useReducer in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, use-context

I'm fetching data from an API using useEffect, this data is updating the context of my application by calling a dispatch function.

I would like the same reducer function that updates the context to also calculate a few new key-value pairs in my response object.

The response object is a list of objects, each of them should have one more key-value pair.

The API response looks as follows:

```
[{ID:'500T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 11400, hours: 212},
           1 : {percentage: 0.6, cycles: 12900, hours: 243},
           2 : {percentage: 0.3, cycles: 10100, hours: 197}]},

 {ID:'584T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.8, cycles: 18400, hours: 277},
           1 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 10500, hours: 184},
           2 : {percentage: 0.9, cycles: 23100, hours: 306}]},

 {ID:'551T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.2, cycles: 10400, hours: 177},
           1 : {percentage: 0.1, cycles: 10500, hours: 184},
           2 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 20100, hours: 106}]}]
```

What I'm trying to do is hand this list to another function that will create another key-value pair for each, calculating the maximum "percentage" and storing it. Please see below for more clarity.

```
[{ID:'500T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 11400, hours: 212},
           1 : {percentage: 0.6, cycles: 12900, hours: 243},
           2 : {percentage: 0.3, cycles: 10100, hours: 197}],
  maxPercentage: 0.6},

 {ID:'584T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.8, cycles: 18400, hours: 277},
           1 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 10500, hours: 184},
           2 : {percentage: 0.9, cycles: 23100, hours: 306}],
  maxPercentage: 0.9},

 {ID:'551T',
  values:[ 0 : {percentage: 0.2, cycles: 10400, hours: 177},
           1 : {percentage: 0.1, cycles: 10500, hours: 184},
           2 : {percentage: 0.4, cycles: 20100, hours: 106}]},
  maxPercentage: 0.4}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the data to a new array. During the mapping map the `values` array to an array of percentages and spread into `Math.max` to return the maximum value. Shallow copy the current `obj` element and add a new `maximumPercentage` key/value property.

```
const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  maxPercentage: Math.max(...obj.values.map(({ percentage }) => percentage))
}));
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    ID: "500T",
    values: [
      { percentage: 0.4, cycles: 11400, hours: 212 },
      { percentage: 0.6, cycles: 12900, hours: 243 },
      { percentage: 0.3, cycles: 10100, hours: 197 }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "584T",
    values: [
      { percentage: 0.8, cycles: 18400, hours: 277 },
      { percentage: 0.4, cycles: 10500, hours: 184 },
      { percentage: 0.9, cycles: 23100, hours: 306 }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "551T",
    values: [
      { percentage: 0.2, cycles: 10400, hours: 177 },
      { percentage: 0.1, cycles: 10500, hours: 184 },
      { percentage: 0.4, cycles: 20100, hours: 106 }
    ]
  }
];

const res = data.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  maxPercentage: Math.max(...obj.values.map(({ percentage }) => percentage))
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was trying to do!! thanks you very much. Not sure if this falls under the realm of "advanced" or just "intermediate" but I didn't even know how to google for this.

Comment: @ortunoa Which aspect? The mapping of one array *into* the next to add a property, or the computing of a maximum value from an array? I would say these are basic level of knowledge items, but it's more like knowing/learning how to break a problem down to smaller parts that are easier to solve.

Comment: Yeah the combination of all, destructuring and then creating new key-value pairs that map to a function. I guess it just has a bunch of moving parts that make it slightly confusing but it works like a charm. I guess this returns an array, correct? ( 
 ...obj.values.map(({ percentage }) => percentage)  )

Comment: @ortunoa Affirmative, `obj.values.map(({ percentage }) => percentage)` generates an array of percentage values, i.e. `[0.4, 0.6, 0.8, ....]` and spreading this into `Math.max` passes all the values in, i.e. like if you had called `Math.max(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, ....)`.

Comment: Won't forget this one, took me almost 2 hours of headbanging before I came here. Thanks again.